# WPF Desktop application and design patterns

Tags: wpf

I have to develop a desktop application and the back end will be SQL Express.
I am new to wpf.

Any design patterns i can use? any sample application for wpf with db?

Please help me.

Comment: Your best bet with WPF would be MVVM.  At the same time, that is my opinion :)

Answer (score 5):

Prism 4 is by Microsoft Patterns and Practices team and it advocates MVVM, Dependency Injection, and modular application development. The book (which I bought and read) is now free online. The book covers several design practices and should be a fairly good start to everything you would need to know to write maintainable, testable, flexible applications in WPF. Prism is also a framework which aids in modular app development and MVVM. It is also fairly popular.

[Prism 4.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx)

^ Seriously, read this book. It takes 2 days max.

Answer (score 0):

As per my suggestion MVVM pattern would be nice if you use in your application. Because it has many ways to reuse your code.

You can find tutorial on the same at below links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

http://wpftutorial.net/MVVM.html

Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MVVM design pattern, It will help you to Reuse of code, Flexibility and Customization, Separation of the UI design and development , Testing ...

Refer these article to understand the MVVM pattern and also for sample WPF application..

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/278901/MVVM-Pattern-Made-Simple

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx